# Dependency Injection Circular Dependency

Tags: dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I've started a new project and have been gradually building my service layer up using ninject and the unit of work pattern. I've come across a problem and am looking for some help.

I have a `LicenceService` that requires access to the `UserService` so the constructor is

```
public LicenceService(IRepository<Licence> licenceRepo, IUserService userService)
```

however I'm now in the situation where my `UserService` needs access to the `LicenceService` so the constructor would be

```
public UserService(IRepository<User> userRepo, ILicenceService licenceService)
```

I'm guessing by this point you can see my circular reference problem. As Imagine this is not an uncommon problem does anybody have any suitable solutions.

Comment: If you can't solve it by changing the design, you can fallback on property injection.

Answer (score 3):

How about a third service to hold references to both and communicate between them?

That is to say that the third service would call both, for specific purposes, rather than one having to know about the other.

Comment: Yep this was on my list of options as well. My issue with this design wise was that I wouldn't know wether to look in my LicenceService or "LicenceUserService" for a method and it may lead to code duplication. This is looking the most likely solution though

Comment: I suppose that it would depend on the logic it's intending to perform, though I would have thought it fairly simple to see at a glance what should and shouldn't be going through the third service. Unless at the point of a feature implementation you find yourself needing both services, put it in one - if you find that you can't perform your action without using both then move it into the third service and co-ordinate between the other two.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with a factory or delegate, but really it's a design issue. See if you can factor out some code into a third class to remove the circular dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about this, would rather not use a delegate. And I can't move out the code into a third class as its dependent on the repository.